# Its about KnockOut JS using MVVM,(Durandal)

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, base64, viewmodel

I am using Input type = FIle to Upload Images to Server, As Input is not giving accurate base64 path of that Image its giving "data\images:base64,", How to get accurate path of an Image so that i can send correctly

Comment: theres not really enough information here, i don't think. in general, when i need to upload a file i use jquery to post a multipart/form-data

Answer (score 0):

Browser security does not allow you to get absolute or full path of image.. You might be able to get it in browsers like Firefox but it is not natively supported by any other browser. UNFORTUNATELY, there is no way to do that.

Here's JSFiddle of what you can get with input type file -

```
$('input[type=file]').change(function () {
      console.dir(this.files[0])
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SCK5A/1505/

Answer (score 0):

self.imagePath("data\images:base64,")

var img =  imagePath().split(',')[1];

Sent img variable  to WebService it worked for Me.